# Letter spacing broken after inline maths in fancy header

Tags: typography

I am struggling to insert inline maths into the header of my thesis (based from Classic thesis).

If I naively put into the section title `$N=2$` this is shown as `$n=2$` within the header, as the lowercase seems to apply to the maths command before rendering.

If I do what I want: `$\mathcal{N}=2$` in the title, then the character from `\mathcal{N}` does not show at all within the header.

I have found a way around this, by replacing `$\mathcal{N}=2$` with `\titleN$=2$` with the definition

```
\newcommand{\titleN}{\texorpdfstring{\MakeUppercase{$\mathcal{N}$}}{N}}
```

However, this then breaks the letter spacing after the inline maths. Image shown below.

Can anyone suggest a better fix to allow me to include the inline maths into the header?

```
\documentclass[10.5pt, twoside]{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{pgf}

\usepackage[paperheight=234mm,
            paperwidth=156mm,
            left=0.75in,
            right=0.75in,
            top=0.8in,
            bottom=0.8in,
            headsep=0.325in,
            ]{geometry}

% Attempt to get maths into header
\newcommand{\titleN}{\texorpdfstring{\MakeUppercase{$\mathcal{N}$}}{N}}

%*******************************************************
% Nice font
%*******************************************************
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Minion Pro}
\usepackage[minionint, onlymath, mathlf]{MinionPro}
\usepackage{amsthm}

%*******************************************************
% Letter Spacing
%*******************************************************
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{textcase}
\RequirePackage{soul} % for letterspacing 
\sodef\allcapsspacing{\upshape}{0.15em}{0.65em}{0.6em}%
\sodef\lowsmallcapsspacing{\scshape}{0.075em}{0.5em}{0.6em}%   
\DeclareRobustCommand{\spacedallcaps}[1]{\MakeTextUppercase{\allcapsspacing{#1}}}%   
\DeclareRobustCommand{\spacedlowsmallcaps}[1]{\MakeTextLowercase{\textsc{\lowsmallcapsspacing{#1}}}}%

%*******************************************************
% Headers and Footers
%*******************************************************

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\textit \thepage}
\fancyhead[RE]{\rightmark}
\fancyhead[LO]{\leftmark}
\fancyfoot[CE,CO]{}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{}

% user spaced small caps in the header of each page
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}{\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}} 


%*******************************************************
% Start of document
%*******************************************************
\begin{document}
\baselineskip=13.5pt

\chapter{Chapter Title}
\section[Solutions to \titleN$=2$ Supergravity]{Solutions to $\mathcal{N}=2$ Supergravity}

\lipsum[2-10]

\end{document}
```

[image: Image showing headers, with correct letter spacing ref and broken letter spacing after inline maths on right]

Comment: Please post a proper [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) that begins with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}` that can be copied and compiled as is that shows the problem. Don't make us guess what document class and other packages you're using.

Comment: Sorry about that, I have now edited the post to include a minimal working example.

Comment: as you're loading microtype anyway, you could use its `\textls` command instead of soul.

Comment: @Robert indeed this is what I did, with `\spaceskip` to also capture the word spacing. I have included full code below as an answer.

Comment: what I meant is something like `\newcommand\lowsmallcapsspacing[1]{\textls[75]{#1}}`, which works with luatex.

Answer (score 1):

So a fix I found was using `{\protect\titleN}` but this clashed with the soul package and produced a black square.

So I've moved away from Soul and typesetting with XeTeX I get the desired result

```
\documentclass[10.5pt, twoside]{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{pgf}

\usepackage[paperheight=234mm,
            paperwidth=156mm,
            left=0.75in,
            right=0.75in,
            top=0.8in,
            bottom=0.8in,
            headsep=0.325in,
            ]{geometry}

%*******************************************************
% Nice font
%*******************************************************
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Minion Pro}
\usepackage[minionint, onlymath, mathlf]{MinionPro}
\usepackage{amsthm}

%*******************************************************
% Letter Spacing
%*******************************************************
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{textcase}

\makeatletter
\protected\def\spacedlowsmallcaps#1{%
 {\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=6.0}\MakeTextLowercase{\spaceskip4pt \scshape{#1}}}%
}
\protected\def\spacedallcaps#1{%
 {\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=18.0}\MakeTextUppercase{#1}}%
}
\makeatother

%*******************************************************
% Headers and Footers
%*******************************************************

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\textit \thepage}
\fancyhead[RE]{\rightmark}
\fancyhead[LO]{\leftmark}
\fancyfoot[CE,CO]{}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{}

% user spaced small caps in the header of each page
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}{\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}} 


\newcommand{\titleN}{\texorpdfstring{$\mathcal{N}=2$}{N}}

%*******************************************************
% Start of document
%*******************************************************
\begin{document}

\baselineskip=13.5pt

\chapter{Chapter Title}
\section[Cosmological Solutions of {\protect\titleN} Supergravity]{Solutions to $\mathcal{N}=2$ Supergravity}

\lipsum[1-4]

\end{document}
```

[image: Correct letter and word spacing...]

Comment: You see from this why some math publishers have chosen to not use small caps for running heads.  Math inclusions don't fare well.